# How to bind a combobox's item background color to a grid's background color?

Tags: c#, combobox

```
<Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid" Background="Navy">

<ComboBox x:Name="BackgroundColor" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="33" Width="66" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,34,10,33" PlaceholderText="" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="BackgroundColor_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Navy"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Red"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Yellow"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Blue"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Green"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

Notice that it's in win8.1, I have searched solutions from internet but I can't use them in win8.1.

Comment: Well, since the selected item would rather be an object that then ComboboxItem, you could rather go for a class that contains the background color (either as text or as brush), and then bind to the selectedItem of the ComboBox. In this case yo wouldn't need your selection changed event ;)

Comment: I see how to bind comboBox with a class, but how to bind a grid to a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most workable approach would be a ViewModel with:

- updates on selection of your combo with a TwoWay binding to SelectedItem
- the grid that listens to the changes of the SelectedItem of the ViewModel

This would require an extra class for the ItemSource of your combobox, as such

```
public class BackgroundColorItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var localEvent = PropertyChanged;
        if (localEvent != null)
        {
            localEvent.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.Equals(title, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    private Brush brush;
    public Brush Brush
    {
        get
        {
            return brush;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Brush.Equals(brush, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            brush = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Brush");
        }
    }
}
```

This class can then be used inside the ViewModel to fill the ItemsSource of your combobox, as such:

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var localEvent = PropertyChanged;
        if (localEvent != null)
        {
            localEvent.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private readonly IList<BackgroundColorItem> items = new ObservableCollection<BackgroundColorItem>();
    public IList<BackgroundColorItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }

    private BackgroundColorItem selectedItem;

    public BackgroundColorItem SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Object.Equals(selectedItem, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        // add the basic items to the ItemCollection during load
        Items.Add(new BackgroundColorItem { Title = "Navy", Brush = Brushes.Navy });
        Items.Add(new BackgroundColorItem { Title = "Red", Brush = Brushes.Red });
        Items.Add(new BackgroundColorItem { Title = "Yellow", Brush = Brushes.Yellow });
        Items.Add(new BackgroundColorItem { Title = "Blue", Brush = Brushes.Blue });
        Items.Add(new BackgroundColorItem { Title = "Green", Brush = Brushes.Green });
    }
```

And in your XAML, you could add the ViewModel as a resource (if necessary, add a new xmlns tag for it (like my xmlns:local)

And then bind the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to the ViewModel.Items

```
<Window x:Class="Win8._1Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Win8._1Binding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ScreenViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{Binding SelectedItem.Brush,Source={StaticResource ScreenViewModel},Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items,Source={StaticResource ScreenViewModel}}" DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Source={StaticResource ScreenViewModel},Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Brush}" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The DisplayMember Path sets the property that is shown inside your ComboBox, the Style resource inside the ComboBox automatically outfits each ComboBoxItem with the Background color binding on the Brush property of BackgroundColorItem.

This keeps your CodeBehind clean of any extra code, the BackgroundColorItem class you could use at other places in your program, and by changing how the values are added to the Items collection inside the ViewModel you could also implement some loading / saving of values